# Pygame "'set_at' for 'pygame.Surface' objects doesn't apply to 'tuple' object"

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am coding a basic program that reads data from a file where each character represents a pixel's color and then displays that info on the screen using pygame.

I've got a block of code that reads the file which works beautifully, but when I try to display the pixels one by one, I get an error that says "descriptor 'set_at' for 'pygame.Surface' objects doesn't apply to 'tuple' object". "Grid" is a 2D array that has the 0 and 1 data from the file.

```py
print("Done processing file, Drawing pixels...")

for i in range(0, height - 2):
    for j in range(0, width - 2):
        if grid[i][j] == 0:
            pygame.Surface.set_at((i, j), "black") #Throws the error
        elif grid[i][j] == 1:
            pygame.Surface.set_at((i, j), "white")

print("Pixels drawn!")
```

I'm trying to use the "i" and "j" values to describe the "x" and "y" of the pixel I want to modify, but pygame seems to be reading that as a different data type than I want? I'm not entirely sure why pygame doesn't expect a tuple for coordinates (seems like the most logical data type for cartesian coordinates to me).

I'm very new to pygame, so I'm hoping this is a relatively simple mistake with an easy fix. If you want the docs for this specific function: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_at

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: surface should be instance of class `pygame.Surface`, not class `pygame.Surface` - ie. `my_surface = pygame.Surface()` and `my_surface.set_at(...)`. Or `screen = pygame.display.set_mode(...)` and `screen.set_at(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not `(x,y)` but `pygame.Surface`.

You have to use instance of class `pygame.Surface`, not class `pygame.Surface`

```
surface = pygame.Surface((800,600))
surface.set_at((i, j), (255,255,255))
```

or

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
screen.set_at((i, j), (255,255,255))
```

or

```
image = pygame.image.load('image.png')
image.set_at((i, j), (255,255,255))
```

or

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
text = font.render("Hello World", True, (255,255,255))
text.set_at((i, j), (255,255,255))
```

---

You will have another problem with color. It has to be tuple `(R,G,B)` - eventually `(R,G,B,A)` if you use transparency (alpha channel).

For `white` it will be `(255,255,255)`, for `black` it will be `(0,0,0)`.

To use string with name you would have to use class `pygame.color.Color(name)`

```
screen.set_at((i, j), pygame.color.Color('white'))
```

---

Example code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#WHITE = pygame.color.Color('white')
WHITE = (255,255,255)

for x in range(100):
    for y in range(100):
        screen.set_at((350+x, 250+y), WHITE)

pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

pygame.quit()
```